# svg innerHTML in firefox can not display

Tags: firefox, svg, innerhtml

i use innerHTML to add svg element,it works fine in chrome but in firefox it can not display; thanks so much for any ansower

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>SVGInnerHTML demo</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="svginnerhtml.js"></script>
        <script>
        alter  = function () {
            var svg = document.getElementById('container');

            svg.innerHTML   = '<rect width="100" height="60" fill="green" />'
                            + '<circle cx="10" cy="19" r="20" fill="blue"></circle>'
                            + '<text x="15" y="20" fill="white">hello world</text>'
                            + '<g transform="translate(0, 70)"><rect width="100" height="20" fill="yellow" /></g>';
        }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <svg id="container" width="100px" height="100px" http://www.w3.org/2000/svg>

    </svg>

    <p>
    <button onclick="alter()">set .innerHTML</button>
    <button onclick="alert(document.getElementById('container').innerHTML)">get .innerHTML</button>
    </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: From Firefox 36 onwards, this should work OK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A workaround is to add the innerHTML code as HTML, and not SVG. You can do that simply by using a `<div>` (instead of `<svg>`) in your HTML code as the placeholder, and insert the full SVG via `innerHTML`.

Replace:

```
<svg id="container" width="100px" height="100px">
</svg>
```

with

```
<div id="container" style="width: 100px; height: 100px">
</div>
```

And wrap your `innerHTML` string within an `<svg>` element:

```
var svg = document.getElementById('container');
svg.innerHTML   = '<svg><rect width="100" height="60" fill="green" />'
                + '<circle cx="10" cy="19" r="20" fill="blue"></circle>'
                + '<text x="15" y="20" fill="white">hello world</text>'
                + '<g transform="translate(0, 70)">'
                + '<rect width="100" height="20" fill="yellow" /></g></svg>';
```

This should work in both Chrome and Firefox. Here's a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/VP5wZ/)**.

Comment: as you say; i chang my code to

`var tempDiv = document.createElement("div");
 tempDiv.innerHTML = "<svg>"+svgEles+"</svg>"
 var svgNodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(tempDiv.childNodes[0].childNodes);
 svgNodes.forEach(function(el){
      container.appendChild(el);
 });`

this work in both chrome and firefox; and easy to fix my old codes
thanks!